# Implementing copy constructor involving windows HANDLE objects

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, winsock, handle

I'm a newbie when it comes to using win32 API, so please bear with me.

I'm currently working on a C++ project that involves Winsock, but I've become confused on the proper way to work with the event object HANDLE type with regards to copy constructors.

An overview (code follows below): In trying to use IOCP and keeping everything scalable, I have a thread that checks for multiple accept events. Each ServerConnection object holds its own accept event object created by WSACreateEvent(), its associated low-level socket, and related states/variables.

My question is, Im trying to implement the 'big three', and I'm not quite sure how I should 'copy' the handle.

DuplicateHandle() seems to create a new handle but it points to the same object, but that does not make sense in terms of a ServerConnection "copy" (We want a new object that just has the same state, right?).

As for using the copy assignment operator, I'm not sure what it would do for event object HANDLEs.

ServerConnection.h

```cpp
class ServerConnection
{
public:
    //...constructors, destructors, etc...

    virtual HANDLE getAcceptEvent();

    virtual void setAcceptEvent(HANDLE eventObj);

protected:

private:

    HANDLE assocAcceptEvent;

    //..other variables...
};
```

ServerConnection.cpp

```cpp
ServerConnection::ServerConnection(ServerConnection &that)
{
   //blah blah...other vars

   //? This does not seem right as the HANDLE is logically a pointer;
   //Assigning like this just points another handle to the same event obj
   //If the other ServerConnection object closes the handle...not good.
   this.assocAcceptEvent = that.assocAcceptEvent;

   //The only thing that make slightly more sense, is just to create a whole new one
   //if I answered my own question, then great...but I wanted to make sure
   this.assocAcceptEvent = WSACreateEvent(); 

   //assume check for WSACreateEvent failing with WSAGetLastError() and
   //handle appropriately
}
```

Comment: Usually the answer is handle the copy by not allowing copies.  In C++11 mark it `=delete`, and in C++03 make it private with no implementation.

Comment: As others said, the object should not be copyable. This is a common choice for objects wrapping OS resources (like `fstreams` in the standard). What you can do in C++11 is making it movable, which does make sense.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that you can't copy the handle in a sensible way (that is, the `DuplicateHandle` doesn't do what you want) makes me think that this object shouldn't be copyable...

The questions you have to ask yourself is:
What does a copy of a ServerConnection actually mean? 
Where/how would you use it?

I don't know the answer, because I don't know what your overall design is means to do with a ServerConnection - but the fact that it says ServerConnection makes me think that it's something that is "connected" to something, and as such can't trivially be copied.

Comment: You're completely right, if you want you can share access but not copy the actual socket.